# CLLocationManager "turn on location services..." alertview customization ios

Tags: cocoa-touch, customization, uialertview, cllocationmanager

I know that I can't change the title or the buttons for this alertview, but i've seen numerous apps that changed the message of the alert view

[image: picture] Something like this

Also, I have the Bump API in my app so everytime the popup shows, it says "Bump uses your location to help determine whom you are bumping." and I don't want that displayed when they first use my app.

Does anybody know how I can change the message or change bump's message?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To change the message of the alert, use the "purpose" property of CLLocationManager. Check the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the Bump API works, but if you are just importing all the classes you need, you should be able to edit the location services message. Otherwise, one option would be to request location access before calling the Bump API's to get permission for your app. Once Bump checks, it will already have permission and skip presenting its own.